# Sterilize PDF files

Tags: security, pdf

I use Linux on my desktop, but I got suprised after checking random PDF files on my machines with Virustotal. One of them contained a "PDF.Exploit.CVE_2008_2992". 
So PDF files can have malicious content in them.

**Question:** How can I "sterilize" a PDF file? I'm thinking of converting a PDF file to a PDF file (maybe remove javascript in them?).

Comment: Maybe convert to Postscript and back to PDF? But Postscript is a turing-complete language so I'm not even sure that's guaranteed. That's all assuming of course that the PDF viewer doesn't have security bugs.

Comment: Print it, then scan it.

Comment: It is not sure what that Virustotal scans for. If it scans for the use of the util.printf() command, but does not evaluate its arguments, it is with a very high probabilty creating a false positive. And it also depends a lot on where that util.printf() command is invoked.

Answer (score 3):

A quick Google searchs turns up the **[PDF Javascript Stripper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfjavascriptst/)**, which appears to do just that.

But bear in mind that PDF is a subset of Postscript, which is a Turing-complete language.  So there may be other attack vectors, not just embedded JavaScript (even if that arguably is the biggest one), and it’s thus mathematically impossible to *know* that your PDF is actually ‘safe’.

If a malicious PDF file targets a vulnerability in a specific PDF reader, or an associated library, then ‘sterilising’ them in a general way either won’t work (and thus give a false sense of security) or would be overzealous and remove too much information.  Just imagine stripping all JPEGs from PDF files to avert the [Microsoft GDI+ JPEG vulnerability](http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/297462)…

Comment: However, for that particular vulnerabilty, the use of util.printf() is the attack vector, and with that gone, it is no longer possible to use it.